# Can't boot FreeBSD 10 iso by PXE

Tags: freebsd, bsd, pxe-boot

I'm trying to boot FreeBSD 10 bootonly iso from with pxelinux and tftp, unfortunately the following error appears during freebsd boot:

> cd9660 :/dev/iso9660 error :/dev/iso9660/FREEBSD_INSTALL failed with error 19
>   mountroot>
>   command ?
>
> List of GEOM managed disk devices:
>       da0s1 da0 ada0

I tried to modify iso file and comment out the line starting with /dev/iso9660 within fstab and to add "root_rw_mount="NO"" to rc.local but it made almost no effect to this problem. Is there any workaround for this problem? Exporting root fs with NFS using "option root-path" is not an option.

P.S I also mentioned that mfsbsd boots just fine with my setup, maybe it's somehow possible to include sysinstall into mfsbsd?

Comment: gPXE has been abandoned for almost 4 years. You should probably migrate to iPXE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sysinstall has been deprecated in FreeBSD 9. The new, and better way, to install FreeBSD is using the bsdinstall software.

If you want to use a Linux Server I would recommend you to create a custom mfsBSD image with FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE as the basis. In this image you can create a custom rc.local file to automatically start bsdinstall and even make an unattended, or partially unattended, installation with a answer file in /etc/installerconfig

If you look in the bsdinstall(8) manual there are infos about the unattended install.

To boot the image from the Linux server you should use memdisk with arguments, like this:

```
#FreeBSD 10.0 RELEASE amd64
label 1
    menu label ^1. FreeBSD 10.0 AMD64
    kernel memdisk 
    append initrd=freebsd/mfsbsd-10.0-RELEASE-amd64.img harddisk raw

#FreeBSD 10.0 RELEASE x86
label 2
    menu label ^2. FreeBSD 10.0 i386
    kernel memdisk
    append initrd=freebsd/mfsbsd-10.0-RELEASE-i386.img harddisk raw
```

You shouldn't create ISOs to network booting, just BUILD plain image files with mfsbsd-2.1. Get it here: http://mfsbsd.vx.sk

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:

I just added a script to sysutils/auto-admin that automatically sets up a PXE server and install image from a standard installation ISO with `bsdinstall`.

It gives you a choice of using PXELINUX to provide a boot menu or go straight to pxeboot image on the installer ISO.

The latest version of the port is not committed yet (as of 2014-11-18), but you can get it [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/freebsdwip/wiki/Home/)